# Query date and specific time in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking for some help in Oracle SQL.  I need to query date and time in the where clause to find shift data based on current date.  There are 3 shifts, 5am to 1pm, 1pm to 9pm and 9pm to 5am(next day morning.  For example

```
SELECT 'T1' AS SHIFT, WORK_CENTER, SUM(CASE WHEN AQL='PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS AQL_PASSED
FROM Z_INSPECTION_DEFECTS
WHERE DATE_TIME >= TO_DATE((SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, ''DD-MON-YYYY''), '' 5:00:00 '') FROM DUAL)  , ''DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS '') AND
       DATE_TIME < TO_DATE((SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, ''DD-MON-YYYY''), '' 1:00:00 '') FROM DUAL) , ''DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS '')
```

I do not get any results from this query.  The date time field is a timestamp on local Los Angeles time.

Comment: Your query has a mix of single, double and escaped single quites, which is a bit confusing. You don't need the inner selects from dual. Is the session time zone also LA (since you're using `current_date` rather than `sysdate`)?

Comment: No the session time zone is UTC.  The date_time field is converted to LA time zone already which why i'm using Current_Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you're looking dor times that are after 5am and before 1am, which logically means nothing matches - as no time can fulfil both at once. You can use 24-hour times instead:

```
WHERE DATE_TIME >= TO_DATE((SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, ''DD-MON-YYYY''), '' 5:00:00 '') FROM DUAL)  , ''DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS '') AND
       DATE_TIME < TO_DATE((SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, ''DD-MON-YYYY''), ''13:00:00 '') FROM DUAL) , ''DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS '')
```

But there are other ways to get those, e.g. just without the queries against `dual`:

```
WHERE DATE_TIME >= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, ''DD-MON-YYYY'') || '' 5:00:00 '', ''DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS '') AND
       DATE_TIME < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, ''DD-MON-YYYY'') || ''13:00:00 '', ''DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS '')
```

or with truncation and date arithmetic:

```
WHERE DATE_TIME >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + (5/24) AND
       DATE_TIME < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + (13/24)
```

You really need to be getting those times in the target time zone though, e.g.:

```
WHERE DATE_TIME >= FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + (5/24) AS TIMESTAMP), ''America/Los_Angeles'') AND
       DATE_TIME < FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + (13/24) AS TIMESTAMP), ''America/Los_Angeles'')
```

You need to be careful with `current_date`, which is in you current session time zone, and `sysdate` which is in the server time zone. If your session is UTC then `current_date` might not give you the day you expect.

(I've stuck with escaped single quotes as that is mostly what you have in the question, implying you're probably running this with dynamic SQL; whether you need to is another matter. If you're only doing that to provide the period offsets at runtime then that wouldn't need to be dynamic...)

You can see the generated times from those calculations with:

```
select FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + (5/24) AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/Los_Angeles'),
       FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + (13/24) AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/Los_Angeles')
from dual;

FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)+(5/24)ASTIMESTAM FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)+(13/24)ASTIMESTA
------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------
2018-10-22 05:00:00.000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES 2018-10-22 13:00:00.000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. You query expertise help me solved this issue.  I've added the sysdate instead of the current_date to ensure I get the date correctly.  Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: how can I get 3rd shift time.  This is what I have, but no results.                                                                     
WHERE DATE_TIME_START >= sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 19/24 as timestamp with time zone))
AND DATE_TIME_START <  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date)+1 + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone))

Comment: 19/24 is 7pm not 9pm; and you seem to have reverted to `current_date`. And I'm not sure why you're now using UTC times - do you in the queries that work for the other shifts? Aside from that, are you sure there is data present for that period? (This seems significiantly different from this question and my answers... it might be better to ask a new question, showing sample data and the queries that do work for the other shifts, plus the one that doesn't find data.)

Comment: It works for 1st and 2nd Shift perfectly.  This is the where clause for 3rd shift. 
 I get data up to 11:59:59pm and then no data after 12am -----WHERE DATE_TIME_START >=sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 21/24 as time stamp with time zone))
AND DATE_TIME_START <  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date)+1 + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone))

Comment: Here's the link to my question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603707/query-date-and-specific-time-in-the-where-clause-3

Comment: Well, that still isn't your actual query as you have a space in 'time stamp'. The adjustments you've shown are right, so I suspect that isn't actually exactly what you're doing; but without seeing your actual query, copied and pasted (not retyped), it's impossible to say what is wrong. (And we have no way to see if you actually have data in yoru table after midnight, of course.)