# Query date and specific time in the where clause 3

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I get 3rd shift data from the where clause.  I'm using current date, but even with what I don't get any resutls. I'm looking to see 3rd shift sale from time range 9pm to 5am ( Next Day ).

```
SELECT WORK_CENTER, SUM(SALES) AS SALES 
FROM ZME_SALES
WHERE DATE_TIME_START >=sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 21/24 as time stamp with time zone))
AND DATE_TIME_START <  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date)+1 + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone))
```

Here's my expected results.

```
SHIFT      WORK_CENTER   SALES
SHIFT-3    8001          1524
SHIFT-3    8002          1347
SHIFT-3    8003          1201
SHIFT-3    8004          1146
```

Comment: Please see new edits.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Done

Comment: The purpose is to show data after 9pm to 5am next day PST time.  If edit the where clause to an earlier time I do get my results I need, but I don't get anything after 12am.

Comment: The easiest way for people on the site to assist you is to have some real data to start from and then assist you in generating your desired result. Ideally you would provide the sample data in the form of inserts into a temp table so that we can copy and paste that to build the query you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do that.  I'm fairly new here.  I've recently asked questions and they were answered without any temp tables or sampled data.  I just wrote the query i'm using with the issue i'm having.  I'm more than free to learn something new here.  If you could help me out here that will be great!

Comment: Just put some starting data in the same way you put the expected results in - as in some rows from `ZME_SALES`.

Comment: You've also tagged SQL Server but you are using Oracle functions - please only tag the correct database.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Oracle do not use T-SQL, it use PL/SQL. I've edited the tags to reflect that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Oracle only uses PL/SQL in stored procedures. A query like the one in the question is "SQL"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. I like nitpicking. I really do, this is not sarcasm.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I think this is actually more than just nitpicking. If you ask a question like "can you help me with my PL/SQL problem" everyone sufficiently experienced with Oracle will answer, "ok, but you have to show me your stored procedure (or function)". A "PL/SQL problem" will usually not be assumed to be a SQL query problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Point taken. Thanks again!